# Can't open Manager App windows on Apache Tomcat/9.0.45 on Winows

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

[EDITED] I know there is a lot of similar questions to mine, but I could not find the one that helped me, I am searching for 4 days now for the resolution. I have successfully installed Apache Tomcat/9.0.45 on my Windows, but when I go on Manager App to log in, Windows is blocking me. I have checked all the permissions and accounts on Windows and in
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\tomcat-users.xml

This is my user XML:

```xml
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp65001'?>
    <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
    <user username="tomcat8272" password="tomcat8272" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" />
    </tomcat-users>
```

I tried changing users, adding roles and users but nothing helped. I checked variables and they are good as well. So when I get to the Manager App it asks me for a username and password, and when I type it in nothing happens.

So, the funny thing is that I did the same thing on the other 2 computers and it worked perfectly fine, but still, on the one that I need most, I can't. I did everything the same on the other computers so I am assuming I have some Windows issues here. I am running Windows 10.

Here is my tomcat9-stderr.2021-04-29 log.

```
2021-04-29 14:14:53 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized.
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.573 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.45
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.578 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:   Mar 30 2021 10:29:04 UTC
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.578 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.45.0
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.578 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:        Windows 10
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:     10.0
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:   amd64
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:      C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_291-b10
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.579 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: abort
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
29-Apr-2021 14:14:54.592 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:55.370 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8272"]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:56.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2186] milliseconds
29-Apr-2021 14:14:56.428 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open The specified user database [conf/tomcat-users.xml] could not be found
29-Apr-2021 14:14:56.430 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:56.431 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:56.444 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:56.904 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] has finished in [459] ms
29-Apr-2021 14:14:56.904 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\examples]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\examples] has finished in [892] ms
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.851 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [54] ms
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.852 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.900 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [49] ms
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.900 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [57] ms
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.964 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8272"]
29-Apr-2021 14:14:57.985 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1617] milliseconds
```

Comment: Please check the details in your question. E.g. do you really have a file named `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\tomcat-users` without `.xml` at the end? The content of this file you posted is not even well formed XML (the closing tag is missing as well as all the content). Check also the startup logs (`tomcat.<date>.log`) and add them to your question.

Comment: Hello Piotr, thanks a lot for your answer. Sorry because of not well-formed XML, it is my first time using StackOverflow. I have added the proper tomcat-users.xml and also attached my date log. 
I really appreciate all of your time and help here.
Thanks.

Comment: When dealing with such problems usually details matter. However if you are sure that `tomcat-users.xml` exists, check if it is readable by the user running Tomcat. The message _"The specified user database [conf/tomcat-users.xml] could not be found"_ is printed on any I/O Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally managed how to solve this issue.

The problem was in tomcat-users.xml

This part:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp65001'?>
```

Should be replaced with:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>
```

Now I can access to Manager App on tomcat.
Thanks everyone for helping me here.